# Bermuda Triangle in angular js: $resource + directive + pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi angular js experts,

I am pretty confused about using $resource, directive and pagination. What I want is to create a table directive which can sort, filter and do the pagination.
There are some already created table component but I am at the beginning of my angularjs learning process so I want to understand how such a thing can be created.
Also I read a lot of forums and stackoverflow threads which I had a partly solution from but still I don't have a working solution.

So I created a directive:

```
app.directive("customTable", function($compile, $document) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var html = "<table><tr>";
        html += "<td style='width: {{ h.width }} px;white-space: nowrap;' ng-repeat='h in headers'>";
        html += "<input style='width: {{ h.width }};display: block;' type='text' ng-model='filters[h.column]'> </td> </tr>";
        html += "<tr ng-repeat='record in customTableData"; 
        var htmlTableTd = "";
        var arrayLength = scope.headers.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            html += " | filter:{" + scope.headers[i].column + ":filters." + scope.headers[i].column + "}";
            htmlTableTd += "<td>{{ record." + scope.headers[i].column + " }}</td>";
        }
        html += "'>";
        html += htmlTableTd;
        html += "</tr> </table>";
        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: link
    };
});
```

And a controller:

```
app.controller("administration.service.controller", function ($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.headers = [
        {column: "name", width: "150px"},
        {column: "serviceType", width: "100px"}
    ];
    $scope.filters = {};
    var serviceManager = $resource("list"); 
    $scope.customTableData = serviceManager.query();
});
```

I tried to use the bootstrap pagination but I should use some filtered customTableData in the directive (in ngRepeat). However as the customTableData is a promise and when the directive is built is hasn't been processed yet so it is empty i.e. the filtered customTableData will be empty too. One solution is to use then(...) method in controller and calling a function of the directive from the controller but I don't know how to do that and it doesn't seem an elegant solution.
Is there any elegant solution for my problem?

Thanks,
Viktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a solution, see below (I used the following 2 samples, thanks for them: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/, http://jsfiddle.net/7czsM/1/)

directive:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});

app.directive("customTable", function($compile, $document) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        // variables for pagination
        scope.currentPage = 0;
        scope.pageSize = 10;
        scope.numberOfPages=function(){
            return Math.ceil(scope.filteredCustomTableData.length/scope.pageSize);                
        }

        // for sorting
        scope.sort = {
            column: '',
            descending: false
        };

        scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
            var sort = scope.sort;
            if (sort.column == column) {
                sort.descending = !sort.descending;
            } else {
                sort.column = column;
                sort.descending = false;
            }
        };

        var arrayLength = scope.headers.length;
        var html = "<table> <tr>";
        // 1. building the header
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            html += "<th ng-click='changeSorting(\"" + scope.headers[i].column + "\")'> " + scope.headers[i].label + " </th>";
        }
        // 2. building the filters
        html += "</tr> <tr> <td style='width: {{ h.width }} px;white-space: nowrap;' ng-repeat='h in headers'>";
        html += "<input style='width: {{ h.width }};display: block;' type='text' ng-model='filters[h.column]'> </td> </tr>";
        // 3. building the table rows
        // sample: <tr ng-repeat='record in (filteredCustomTableData = (customTableData | filter:{name:filters.name} | filter:{serviceType:filters.serviceType}) | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending')>"
        html += "<tr ng-repeat='record in (filteredCustomTableData = (customTableData";

        var htmlTableTd = "";
        // first creating the filters in the ngRepeat (| filter:{name:filters.name} | filter:{serviceType:filters.serviceType}| ...)
        // and after that adding the real table rows -> 
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            html += " | filter:{" + scope.headers[i].column + ":filters." + scope.headers[i].column + "}";
            htmlTableTd += "<td>{{ record." + scope.headers[i].column + " }}</td>";
        }
        html += " | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending) | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize)'>";
        html += htmlTableTd;
        html += "</tr> </table>";

        // adding the pagination buttons
        html += "<button ng-disabled='currentPage == 0' ng-click='currentPage=currentPage-1'>Previous</button>{{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}";
        html += "<button ng-disabled='currentPage >= filteredCustomTableData.length/pageSize - 1' ng-click='currentPage=currentPage+1'>Next</button>";

        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: link
    };

});
```

controller:

```
app.controller("administration.service.controller", function ($scope, $resource) {

    $scope.headers = [
        {column: "name", width: "150px", label: "Name"},
        {column: "serviceType", width: "100px", label: "Service Type"}
    ];

    $scope.filters = {};

    var serviceManager = $resource("list");

    $scope.customTableData = serviceManager.query();
});
```